# AWS Batch - Access denied 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-ecs, amazon-athena

I am using **AWS Batch** with **ECS** to perform a job which need to send a request to **Athena**. I use **python** **boto3** to send the query and the get the request status :

- start_query_execution : **work fine**
- get_query_execution : **have an error !**

When  I try to get the query execution I have the following error :

```
{'QueryExecution': {'QueryExecutionId': 'XXXX', 'Query': "SELECT * FROM my_table LIMIT 10 ", 'StatementType': 'DML', 'ResultConfiguration': {'OutputLocation': 's3://my_bucket_name/athena-results/query_id.csv'}, 'QueryExecutionContext': {'Database': 'my_database'}, 'Status': {'State': 'FAILED', 'StateChangeReason': '**Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 4.**. ; S3 Extended Request ID: ....=)'
```

I have the all permissions to the container role (only to test) :

- s3:*
- athena : *
- glue : *

I face this problem only in container in AWS batch : with the same policy and code in a lambda it's working !

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In Athena Output location what I have been using Athena bucket name not file name.
As result set will be generated which will have its own id

```
'ResultConfiguration': {'OutputLocation': 's3://my_bucket_name/athena-results/'}
```

If ypu are not sure of the bucket for query you can check in query console -->settings
[image]